# Uniform Continuity of a Certain Function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I am currently studying for a qualifying exam, and I came across the following question:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y$. Suppose that there exists $a,M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x \in [-a,a]$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I am not sure how to approach this question. I have attempted to use an epsilon-delta argument, but that did not prove effective. I also thought that if we could show that $f$ is continuous on $[-a,a]$, then we would have uniform continuity by the compactness of $[-a,a]$. However, this still wouldn't give us that $f$ is uniformly continuous everywhere. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't know if it would work,  but maybe you could use the additive property to extend continuity to larger areas?

Comment: You only need to show that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim #1**: $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is continuous at $x=0$

**Proof of Claim #1**: Notice $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)=2f(0)$ which means $f(0)=0$. Now let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Find a positive integer $n$ so that $\frac{M}{n}<\epsilon$, then put $\delta:=\frac{a}{n}$. Notice  $x\in (-\delta,\delta)$ implies $nx\in(-a,a)$ and so $$|f(x)|=\Bigg|\frac{f(x)+\dots+f(x)}{n}\Bigg|=\Bigg|\frac{f(nx)}{n}\Bigg|\leq \frac{M}{n}<\epsilon$$ This shows $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

**Claim #2**: $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

**Proof of Claim #2**: We get $f(x)+f(-x)=f\big(x+(-x)\big)=f(0)=0$ so $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

**Claim #3**: $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

**Proof of Claim #3**: Since $f$ is continuous at $0$, we can find $\delta>0$ so that $|x|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)|<\epsilon$. Choose $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$. Then $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)+f(-y)|=|f(x-y)|<\epsilon$$ and we're done.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Great proof!

Comment: Thank you!! :-D